# C++ Template container with two template param, storing in template class's field

Tags: c++, templates, containers

```
template<class TNodeValue>
struct Node
{
    Node* next;
    TNodeValue value; //need to store here TPair<typename Tkey, typename Tvalue>. Got C2512 error: no appropriate default consturctor available.
    Node();
    Node(TNodeValue _value);
};
template<typename TNodeValue>
Node<TNodeValue>::Node()
{
    next = NULL;
    value = NULL;
}
template<typename TNodeValue>
Node<TNodeValue>::Node(TNodeValue _value)
{
    next = NULL;
    value = _value;
}
```

TPair code:

```
template <typename Tkey, typename Tvalue>
struct TPair
{
    Tkey key;
    Tvalue value;

    TPair(Tkey _key, Tvalue _value)
    {
        key = _key;
        value = _value;
    }

};
```

Code to call error:

```
TPair<int, int> a(1, 2);
Node<TPair<int, int> > node(a);
```

The question is why does it won't to be stored? Why TNodeValue can't store something like TPair? Got C2512 error. 
IMPORTANT: Don't use std lib.

Comment: This "question" makes very little sense. What *is* your question?

Comment: I've updated post. Is it more clear now?

Comment: No, you still haven't asked a question, and there isn't near enough context to tell what you're talking about.

Comment: The question is why does TPair<int,int> won't to be stored? Why TNodeValue can't store something like TPair?

Comment: @АлександрТрифонов try https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

`TPair<int, int>` has no default constructor, so the `Node<TPair<int, int>>` constructors are ill-formed as they both attempt to invoke the default constructor for this type.

There's noding to be node for the `Node` default constructor since you have no constructor arguments with which to construct your `value` member, but the other constructor should use the initializer list to construct `value`:

```
// From C++11 and on, do this:
template<typename TNodeValue>
Node<TNodeValue>::Node(TNodeValue && _value)
    : next(nullptr), value(std::forward(_value)) { }

// Before C++11, do this:
template<typename TNodeValue>
Node<TNodeValue>::Node(TNodeValue const &_value)
    : next(0), value(_value) { }
```

Even though you have `value = _value;`, since you don't use the initializer list, the code is asking for default-construction of the `value` member followed by copy-assignment of `value` from `_value` -- since the type of `value` has no default constructor, this `Node` constructor fails to instantiate.

You could also consider adding a default constructor to `TPair`.

Comment: >"You could also consider adding a default constructor to TPair."
It works.. I can't imagine why, because I didn't use this constructor, I didn't create any var via this constructor. My thanks, sir.

Comment: Let's put it this way: for any members not specified in a constructor's initializer list, those members are implicitly default-constructed. That means you're calling for default construction of Node's value member simply by not initializing it in the Node constructors' initializer lists.